# What does two IP-addresses using the same MAC-address mean?

Tags: ip, mac-address

When doing forensics, I saw the same MAC-address being used by two different IP-addresses in a splunk logfile:

```
139...  4681.791993  Apple_5a:77:9b  Apple_69:38:cc  ARP  64    192.168.1.64 is at 00:1f:f3:5a:77:9b
133...  4380.593992  Apple_5a:77:9b  Apple_69:38:cc  ARP  64  169.254.90.183 is at 00:1f:f3:5a:77:9b
```

What does that mean?

Comment: One of those IPs in a private address space, this is probably the same machine. How did you acquire your scan info?

Comment: from a log file, i am using splunk.

Comment: @iain Both are Private IPs. The second is APIPA Adress that gets selected if no DHCP or static IP is present

Comment: @MartinFischer I have learned something new!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would read your logs as follows:

- 192.168.1.64 is the IPv4 address the physical interface with MAC 00:1f:f3:5a:77:9b is using. I would tend to assume the IP was handed out via DHCP, but you would see a similar IP <-> MAC map if it was statically assigned (you simply would not be likely to see it from a DHCP server)
- 169.254.90.183 is a link-local address (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address), which in effect means it is an autoconfigured address the machine assigned to itself when all other IP assignment mechanisms failed (typically, this would happen when a node cannot get a DHCP assignment, potentially because the DHCP server has no free IPs to hand out, or because it is busy).

If the first two columns in your output are a reasonable proxy for timestamps, I would take all this to mean DHCP failed temporarily, before working again and providing the host with an address.

As a link-local address, traffic from 169.254/16 will not leave the broadcast domain, so in a forensic context, unless something happened within the broadcast domain, I would disregard it.

There is one specific use of this range that would possibly be worthwhile worrying about, which is a host announcing itself as 169.254.169.254 within a cloud environment (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)

Comment: Thanx for clear answer

Comment: @kaplangoz don´t forget to accept the answer (check marker below the rating of this answer)